# Convolutional neural network concept

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Please go to the link http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/flat.html
and draw a number in the box provided to see through various layers.
Now if you scroll through the different squares of the layers, you can see how your square is related to other squares of previous layers.
Now my doubt is, according to cs231n lecture 7, http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ a filter has the same depth as the depth of the respective layer, and number of filters is equal to the depth of the succeeding layer. But if you go through the convolution layer 2, you can see that the particular square of a particular layer is only obtained from some of the squares of the preceding layer. I am trying to understand the concept here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following dimensions are according to (N, C, H, W).

```
pool1('6', 14, 14)
|
| kernel(16, '6', 5, 5)
v
conv2(16, 10, 10)
|
| kernel(2, 2), stride(2)
v
pool2(16, 5, 5)
```

Pool1 output `6` feature maps which are the input of Conv2. Accordingly, Conv2 has 16 kernels(which will generate 16 feature maps) and each of them has same *depth* or *channel* with Pool1 which is `6`(surrounded by single quotes).